# Codeigniter routing if not

Tags: codeigniter, routes

I want to configure codeigniter routing something like this

This is working good

```
$route['login/(:any)']  = "login/index/$1";
$route['profile/(:any)']  = "profile/index/$1";
```

But i want to do this
if not = login or profile then i want to do this

```
$route['not(login or profile)']          = "home/index/$1";
```

This code is not right so please help me by give me code for this.

i have 3 controller they are
1. home
2. profile
3. login

Now if i go with this
domain.com/profile
then i want run profile controller, and if i go with
domain.com/profile/john
i need go get this name **john** from my controller
domain.com/profile/john/edit
i also need to get this **john** and **edit** from controller.

Now if i go with this

```
domain.com/login
```

then i want run profile controller, and if i go with

```
domain.com/login/best
```

i need go get this name **best** from my controller

```
domain.com/login/best/sure
```

i also need to get this **best** and **sure** from controller.

And if i go with

```
domain.com/
or domain.com/bestoffer
or domain.com/others
or domain.com/blabla
```

anything after domain without profile and login i need to run **Home** controller

That's all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Precedence is important here, your routes will be parsed from top to bottom, and the first match it finds, apply to routing,

So, lets say your route file looks like,

```
$route['login/(:any)']  = "login/index/$1";
$route['profile/(:any)']  = "profile/index/$1";
$route['(:any)']  = "controller/index/$1";
```

So, third rule here will be parsed as it is not `login/(:any)` and not `profile/(:any)`.

---

To get parameters in your controller,

```
echo $this->uri->segment(1);
```

Put third rule in your route file at last, and segment block in controller to see it in effect.

Comment: i did not getting data from other directory like this
domain.com/profile/john
I need to get this **john** name

Comment: you want `john` in your controller file or routes file ?

Comment: if user input john i want to get it from controller if user input blue i then also need to get it from controller.

Comment: updating my post with more clear about my requirements now

Comment: I'm using this

`$route['login/(:any)']   = "login/index/$1";
$route['profile/(:any)'] = "profile/index/$1";
$route['(:any)']         = "home/index/$1";`

But if i open domain.com/login it's running **home** controller :(

Comment: @SilaKhatun that is because, before `$route['login/(:any)']` you need to put one more line `$route['login'] = "login/index";`

Comment: Thanks you so much.

Comment: sir, one more help please, when i try **domain.com/login/john** but not it's calling home controller again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
$route['(:any)'] = "home/index/$1";
```

Comment: It's not transferring sub route like this
domain.com/something
but i did not getting this something from controller.

Comment: sorry i did not getting data from other directory like this
domain.com/profile/john
I need to get this **john** name

Comment: do you want to load home/index/$1 only when controller dose'nt exist?

Comment: I included with full clear details please check for me. Thanks